# How to read only new files in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Im reading csv files with spark and scala,the files are coming from another spark streaming job.
I need to read only the new files ?

```
val df= spark  
.read // 
.schema(test_raw)
.option("header", "true")    
.option("sep", ",")   
.csv(path).toDF().cache() 
event3.registerTempTable("test")
```

Comment: Add a checkpoint path

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by adding a checkpoint on the dataframe like this

```
val df= spark  
.read // 
.schema(test_raw)
.option("header", "true")    
.option("sep", ",")   
.csv(path).toDF().checkpoint().cache()
```